# Values overwriting in a stacked Column chart using MpChart

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, mpandroidchart

The values are overwriting each other in a stacked Column chart.
I am using flutter and the lib MpCharts.

[image]

I believe the reason this happen is because the slice of the chart, sometimes is not big enough to fit the value, so he throw him to the closest one.

Thats ok, but how to make them stack over each other, and not overwrite?

This is the part of the code where I format the values:

```
controller.data = new BarData(barData.dataSets);
controller.data.barWidth = 0.35;
controller.data.setValueTextColor(Colors.white);
controller.data.setValueFormatter(MPValuesFormatter(values: true));
```